# Send a MT SMS with Authentication

Tags: c#, sms, smpp

What is the step by step process of Sending a MT SMS with Authentication in SMPP clients? I'm really sorry if I asked an unrelated question.

Comment: Add more detail, like what you wish to achieve and why.

Comment: You need to go through a gateway server to send a short message.  Usually sending message through a mail server is the best way of going.

Comment: page 21 of the spec http://www.smstrade.de/pdf/smpp.pdf

Comment: Did any of the answers help? It's best to post it formally for further readers

Comment: I got the answer. Here is the one I analysed. http://www.rfwireless-world.com/images/SMS-MO-MT-call-flow.jpg

Comment: I followed this link http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Articles/SMS-MO-MT-call-flow.html